# Is глазу locative in the phrase "с глазу на глаз"?

Tags: грамматика, падежи

с глазу на глаз

I don't think глазу is genitive here. Is глазу́ locative and stressed on the last syllable, although с usually takes the genitive?

Answer (score 5):

It actually *is* the genitive, and the stress is on the first syllable:

- с гла́зу на́ глаз

The genitive ending -у is retained in quite a few set expressions such as:

- бе́з толк**у**, и́з лес**у**, не зна́я бро́д**у** не су́йся в во́ду

Stressed prepositions and particles are also signs of a well-established expression or just a frequently-used collocation:

- бе́з году неде́ля, встать на́ ноги, взять за́ руку, не́ за что, etc.

Comment: what about "ни в одном глазу"? - I believe it might be locative

Comment: or "на голубом глазу"

Comment: @shabunc, yes, in "ни в одном глазу" and "на голубом глазу" the "глазу" is in locative as indicated by the stress: глазу́. Also, the prepositions **в/на** only govern prepositional/locative and accusative.

Answer (score 3):

It is ablative case, a subcase of Genitive. It differs from Genitive in ending and from Partitive and Locative in stress: the stress falls on the preposition if it has a vowel.

и́з лесу, и́з виду, и́з глазу, бе́з толку.

When there is no vowel, the stress fall to the noun: с миру.

The other answer is wrong: the word бро́ду in the examples is actually in Partitive, not Ablative.